# Python: Azure Function gets triggered repeatedly

Tags: python, azure-functions

I have an azure function that uses storage blob trigger when a new blob is created in a container. The function also copies the same blob to a directory in the root of the same container.

The function works as expected however, when this happens, the function gets triggered again. It appears that the repeated trigger is happening because the function is monitoring the "encrypteddata" container for blob changes, including changes within its subdirectories like "archiveddata". I am trying to prevent the function from being triggered again when the input blob is copied to the "archiveddata" directory. Is there way to achieve this by updating the blob trigger configuration in the functions.json file like excluding "encrypteddata/archiveddata/*"?

****init**.py**

```
# Import the required modules
import datetime, logging, base64, os # base64 is used to decode the base64-encoded secret
import azure.functions as func # azure.functions is used to create Azure Functions

from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential # Create a DefaultAzureCredential object
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient # SecretClient is used to access Azure Key Vault secrets
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient #

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend


# Azure Key Vault details are stored in environment variables
# Set the Key Vault URL and the secret name in the environment variables
vault_url = os.environ["VAULTURL"] # e.g. https://<vault-name>.vault.azure.net
secret = os.environ["SECRET"] # e.g. my-key

# Define the function to get the secret from Azure Key Vault
def get_secret_from_key_vault():
    # Use DefaultAzureCredential object to authenticate with Azure Key Vault
    credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()

    # Create SecretClient object to access Azure Key Vault
    secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=vault_url, credential=credentials)

    # Retrieve the secret from Azure Key Vault
    secret_value = secret_client.get_secret(secret).value

    # Decode the base64-encoded secret and return the bytes format
    secret_bytes = base64.b64decode(secret_value)
    return secret_bytes

# Define the function to decrypt the input blob
def aes_decrypt(ciphertext, key, iv):
    # OpenSSL backend is used to provide the cryptography library with the correct implementation
    backend = default_backend()

    # Create the cipher object to decrypt the input blob using the AES-CBC algorithm
    # Algoritm: AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) is a block cipher
    # Mode: CBC (Cipher Block Chaining) is a mode of operation for block ciphers
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=backend)

    # Combine AES algorithm with CBC mode to create a decryptor object
    decryptor = cipher.decryptor()

    try:
        decrypted_data = decryptor.update(ciphertext) + decryptor.finalize()
        unpadder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).unpadder() # Remove the padding from the decrypted data
        plaintext = unpadder.update(decrypted_data) + unpadder.finalize()
        return plaintext # Return the decrypted data
    except ValueError as e: # Catch the exception if the padding is invalid
        logging.error("Decryption error:", e) # Print the error message
        return None # Return None if the padding is invalid

def get_container_name_from_blob_url(blob_url):
    # The input blob URL format is "<storage_account_url>/<container_name>/<blob_name>"
    parts = blob_url.split('/')
    return parts[3]  # Index 3 contains the container name

# The function takes the encrypted blob as input and outputs the decrypted blob
# It uses the Azure Key Vault to decrypt the secret key used to decrypt the input blob
# It uses the AES-CBC algorithm to decrypt the input blob
# It uses the unpad function to remove the padding from the decrypted data
# It uses the base64 function to encode the decrypted data to a valid base64 string
# It outputs the decrypted data as a byte array

def main(encryptedcsv: func.InputStream, decryptedcsv: func.Out[func.InputStream]):
    # Set up logging configuration
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    # Retrieve the secret from Azure Key Vault
    secret_key = get_secret_from_key_vault()

    # Use a random IV for AES-CBC
    iv = os.urandom(16) # 16 bytes

    # Read the input blob as a base64-encoded string
    encrypted_data = base64.b64decode(encryptedcsv.read())

    # Copy the encrypted blob to "archiveddata" directory and append "_encrypted.csv"
    try:
        # Get the current local time as a string formatted with the timestamp
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
        logging.info(f"Timestamp: {timestamp}")

        # Get the name of the input blob from the metadata property of the encryptedcsv parameter
        input_blob_name = os.path.basename(encryptedcsv.name)
        archived_input_blob_name = f"archiveddata/{input_blob_name[:-4]}_{timestamp}.csv"
        logging.info(f"Input blob name: {input_blob_name}")
        logging.info(f"Archived input blob name: {archived_input_blob_name}")

        # Get the name of the container from the input blob URL
        container_name = get_container_name_from_blob_url(encryptedcsv.uri)
        logging.info(f"Container name: {container_name}")

        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(os.environ["STORAGE"])
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=input_blob_name)
        logging.info(f"Blob client: {blob_client.url}")

        new_blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=archived_input_blob_name)
        new_blob_client.start_copy_from_url(blob_client.url)

        logging.info("Blob copied to archiveddata directory.")

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error copying the blob: {e}")
        return

    # Decrypt CSV file using the secret key and IV provided above
    decrypted_data = aes_decrypt(encrypted_data, secret_key, iv) # Decrypt the input blob

    if decrypted_data is not None: # If the decryption was successful, write the output blob as a byte array
        decryptedcsv.set(decrypted_data) # Write the output blob
        logging.info("Decryption successful.")
    else: # If the decryption was not successful, print an error message
        logging.info("Decryption failed.")
```

**functions.json**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "encryptedcsv",
      "path": "encrypteddata/{name}",
      "connection": "STORAGE",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "blobTrigger"
    },
    {
      "name": "decryptedcsv",
      "path": "decrypteddata/{name}",
      "connection": "STORAGE",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "blob"
    }
  ]
}
```